Borland C specify symbol name in function declaration
If I declare an external function in a C source file compiled with bcc32.exe (Borland C++ compiler, tested with the free version 5.5.1), it prepends an _ in the .obj file, for example,
extern int answer(int a, int b);

generates the symbol _answer in the .obj file.
How can I control this, to specify an arbitrary symbol, e.g. myanswer, without a leading underscore?
For example, in GCC, Clang, PCC and TinyCC, it's extern int answer(int a, int b) __asm___("myanswer");. Watcom  C respects #pragma aux answer "myanswer" after the usual function declaration.
I've just checked that bcc32.exe version 5.5.1 accepts #pragma alias "_answer" = "myanswer" (see the documentation), and all that does is inserting an ALIAS record to tho OMF .obj file. An answer(6, 7) call from C still emits a call _answer instruction, just like without the #pragma alias. Thus this is useful only if the linker supports the ALIAS record.
One of my use cases is importing functions from DLLs without a .def file or an import library (.lib). Some of the DLLs contain weird function names (such as char, which won't compile in C or C++, because it's a reserved word), and I'd like bcc32.exe to create a call char instruction without having to name the C function char.

If you were exporting the function in a DLL, you could use a .def file to specify the desired export name (myanswer) for the actual function (_answer). But, if you just want to change the symbol name in the .obj file, I don't think bcc32 has an option for that. Maybe #pragma alias, but I'm not sure if the free  version has that.

@RemyLebeau Hmm, I used this compiler a lot back in the days but I don't recall using a .def file for DLLs. Rather, I used __declspec (dllexport) and then it spat out a DLL without any name mangling. Or for C++ extern "C" __declspec (dllexport).

@Lundin __declspec has nothing to do with name mangling. But using extern "C" in C++ will (among other things) disable name mangling. The __cdecl calling convention (the default if no convention is specified) will still output a leading underscore on a function symbol, though.

@RemyLebeau Ah so dllexport was just the same thing as "stdcall"? Either way I don't remember ever having any problems with this when I used bcc32 to create DLLs and I didn't use any .def file.

@Lundin no, __declspec and __stdcall are two completely unrelated things. __declspec attaches extra attributes to a declaration. __stdcall is a calling convention (controls parameter passing, stack management, etc) , like __cdecl, __fastcall, etc.

@RemyLebeau Well according to MS documentation, I seem to be correct after all. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-170  "Declaring functions as dllexport eliminates the need for a module-definition (.def) file" Given that bcc32 behaves accordingly - it probably does.

@pts Is there a reason why you need it to be myanswer rather than answer without underscore? Is the purpose to link the object files to create a DLL?

@Lundin You are mixing your facts. Yes, __declspec(dllexport) does the same thing that a .def file can do (but a .def is much more than just exports). That has nothing to do with the calling convention, which effects the function itself

@RemyLebeau: Yes, bcc32.exe version 5.5.1 supports #pragma alias, I've updated my answer. It looks useful, but it doesn't answer my question directly.

@pts "One of my use cases is..." - in that case, I don't think bcc32 supports what you are looking for. In 30 years of using Borland/Embarcadero C++ compilers, I've never heard of anyone trying to do what you are asking for.
